# jQuery is not defined when trying to test legacy jQuery plugin using Chai & Mocha

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write a unit test for old jQuery plugin. I am kind of new in modern Javascript environment. I have tried creating unit test for React that uses browserify for deploying in production.

The legacy jQuery plugin file is like below

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myLegacyPlugin = function() {
        alert('Hello World!');
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This file will be uploaded to S3 and accessed via CDN. The jQuery will be included in normal browser head tag.

The test file is like below.

```
let expect = require('chai').expect;
let path = require('path');
let $ = require('jquery');

require('../src/plugin.js');

describe('plugin', () => {
    it('should return okay', () => {
        expect(true).to.be.true; //TODO
    });
});
```

The problem is that when I tried executing the test, the runner displays `jQuery is not defined`. Without modifying the legacy jQuery plugin, how do I test the plugin?

The code is here https://github.com/petrabarus/js-test-jquery-legacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying few possibilities, instead of using module import, I can just use read file and evaluate the script content.

Only change

```
require('../src/plugin.js');
```

to this

```
eval(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../src') + '/plugin.js', 'utf8'));
```

This way I don't have to modify the legacy file.

Answer (score -1):

It might be that you are requiring jquery as "$" and passing it to plugin as "jQuery". Although jquery should be defined with both names, regardless.
Could you try requiring jquery like so:

```
let jQuery= require('jquery');
```

Answer 2:
actually, if your code (plugin) depends on jquery, your plugin.js should require jquery before loading..

so change plugin.js to

```
let $ = require('jquery');
// rest of plugin code...
```